# Boiler Flame Pattern

Tags: boiler, gas-burner

I have a propane fueled boiler for all my hot water / heating needs in USA. I was looking at the flame pattern today, it was louder than normal and “stuttering” on the left 3 burners . The right ones were purring. [image]Not sure if this video will upload . [image]

Comment: That's not normal.  I strongly recommend you call in a qualified service technician.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I agree: you need in-person help, and we can't provide that. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: IIRC my furnace did a similar thing when it threw over temperature errors.  The heat exchanger was clogged.  Call a qualified service person.

Comment: Thanks folks one tech is on his way !